# Some isomorphisms of rings in basic $p$-adic Hodge theory

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

When learning $p$-adic Hodge theory, I encountered many non-Noetherian rings that are far from classical algebraic geometry. The following questions, roughly speaking the correctness of each non-inline formula with tag, maybe routine to check, are something perhaps too basic to find in literature and I will be glad if they have explicit and firm answers. I have given reasonings to formulas tagged without star, but you may check if there is any errors. Those with a single star mean I haven't really check it yet but pretty sure they are correct. Those with two stars mean I am not sure with the result.

(1) Consider the expression $A[X_1^{p^{-\infty}},\dots,X_n^{p^{-\infty}}]$. It might be

1. The direct union of $A[X_1^{p^{-i}},\dots,X_n^{p^{-i}}]$.
2. The colimit of the $\mathbb{N}$-indexed diagram $A[X] \to A[X]$ given by $X_i \to X_i^p$.

These two are isomorphic since the corresponding direct systems are isomorphic. Similarly we have $A[\![X_1^{p^{-\infty}},\dots,X_n^{p^{-\infty}}]\!]$. Moreover, we should have
\begin{equation} A[X_1^{p^{-\infty}},\dots,X_n^{p^{-\infty}}] \simeq A[X_1^{p^{-\infty}}]\dots[X_n^{p^{-\infty}}], \tag{*1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 A[\![X_1^{p^{-\infty}},\dots,X_n^{p^{-\infty}}]\!] \simeq A[\![X_1^{p^{-\infty}}]\!]\dots[\![X_n^{p^{-\infty}}]\!]. \tag{*2}
\end{equation}

Now suppose $A$ is a domain. Then one can take compatible $p$-power roots $\tilde{X_i}^{p^{-\infty}}$ of $X_i$ in a fixed algebraic closure of the field of fractions of $A$. I think
$$A[{X_i}^{p^{-\infty}}] \simeq A[\tilde{X_i}^{p^{-\infty}}].\tag{*3}$$ In fact, there is a natural homomorphism for the corresponding direct system. It should suffice to look at the case of a single variable, saying $A[X,Y]/(Y^p - X) \simeq A[X][\tilde{X}^{1/p}]$. This follows from $A[X,Y]/(Y^p - X) \simeq A[Y]$.

Moreover, I guess
\begin{equation}
A[\![X_1^{p^{-\infty}},\dots,X_n^{p^{-\infty}}]\!] \simeq A[\![X_1,\dots,X_n]\!][\tilde{X_1}^{p^{-\infty}},\dots,\tilde{X_n}^{p^{-\infty}}] \tag{**4}
\end{equation}
where $\tilde{X}_i^{p^{-j}}$ are compatible systems of $p$-th power roots in an algebraic closure.

(2) I thought these were difficult but just come up the idea of proof while typing.
For $I$ an ideal of $A$, there should be an isomorphism
$$
A[X]^{\wedge(I,X)} \simeq  A^{\wedge I}[\![X]\!] \tag{5}
$$
where $^{\wedge I}$ denotes $I$-adic completion.
In fact,
$$
\lim_n A[X]/(I,X)^n = \lim_{m,n} A[X]/(I^m,X^n) = \lim_{n} \lim_m (A/I^m)[X]/(X^n) =
\lim_{n} A^{\wedge I}[X]/X^n.
$$
The last equality is because limits commutes with finite direct sums.

Besides, if $I$ is finitely genereted then $A[\![X]\!]/IA[\![X]\!] \simeq (A/I)[\![X]\!]$, thus
$$
\lim_n A[\![X]\!]/I^n = \lim_n (A/I^n)[\![X]\!] = \lim_n \lim_m (A/I^n)[X]/(X^m) = A^{\wedge I}[\![X]\!].
$$
That is,
$$
A[\![X]\!]^{\wedge IA[\![X]\!]} \simeq A^{\wedge I}[\![X]\!]. \tag{6}
$$

(3) Now combine (1) and (2). Let $f$ be a non zero-divisor on $A$. All following completions are $f$-adic except otherwise specified.
Denote $A\langle X_1,\dots,X_n \rangle = A[X_1,\dots,X_n]^{\wedge} $.
As $\hat A[X]^\wedge /f^n = \hat A[X]/f^n = (\hat A/f^n)[X]$, we have
$$
A\langle X \rangle = \hat A \langle X \rangle \tag{7}.
$$
Thus by induction we have
$$
A\langle X_1,\dots,X_n \rangle = A\langle X_1\rangle\dots\langle X_n \rangle.
\tag{8}
$$

Now denote $ A\langle X_1^{p^{-\infty}}, \dots, X_n^{p^{-\infty}} \rangle = (A[X_1^{p^{-\infty}}, \dots, X_n^{p^{-\infty}}])^\wedge$.

I expect that
$$
A\langle X^{p^{-\infty}} \rangle  \simeq \hat A \langle X^{p^{-\infty}} \rangle. \tag{9}
$$

In fact, there should be an isomorphism for any $A$-algebra $B$:
$$
B[X_1^{p^{-\infty}}, \dots, X_n^{p^{-\infty}}] \simeq A[X_1^{p^{-\infty}}, \dots, X_n^{p^{-\infty}}] \otimes_A B \tag{10}
$$
since the formation of direct limit commutes with tensor product.

Thus there should be an ismorphism
$$
  A\langle X_1^{p^{-\infty}}, \dots, X_n^{p^{-\infty}}\rangle \simeq A\langle X_1^{p^{-\infty}}\rangle \dots\langle X_n^{p^{-\infty}}\rangle \tag{*11}
$$
granting (*1).

Also, I feel
$$
A\langle X^{p^{-\infty}}\rangle \simeq (\mathrm{colim}_{X \to X^p} A\langle X\rangle )^\wedge = (\cup_i A\langle X^{p^{-i}} \rangle)^\wedge. \tag{12}
$$

Usually there is a strict inclusion $A[\![X]\!] \otimes_A B \subset B[\![X]\!]$. But I wonder if
$$
(A[\![X]\!] \otimes_A B)^{\wedge X} \simeq B[\![X]\!] \tag{**13}.
$$
Still one may expect that
$$
(A [\![X^{p^{-\infty}}]\!])^\wedge \simeq (\hat{A} [\![X^{p^{-\infty}}]\!])^\wedge \tag{14}.
$$
This is independent to (13) since $A[\![X]\!]/f \simeq (A/f)[\![X]\!]$, and the formation of quotients commutes with direct limits.

Comment: [Titles should be clear and informative](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144) - I've made an attempt to improve the title here, but there might be an even better way to state it. If you can think of a better one, please consider upgrading it further :)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @reuns The question is the correctness of each non-inline identity.